# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' in vscode

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I make env conda, so in terminal python 'import tensorflow' not occuring error

but execute file, example test.py import tensorflow

no module name tensorflow

terminal python find tensorflow but why execute test.py  can not find tensorflow?

in terminal , ok   but file execute cannot find module

how can it occuring?????

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, your question does not give any useful information and no provided code.  To create a question please show what you have tried and make sure your question is properly worded.  This is only so that other developers can help you.

Comment: Mb you run different Python versions: in term and in vscode, check the path to the python interpreter in the vsc config. Also check where the module is installed, mb in virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check whether the right environment you creat.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iEBh.png)